# While import product in magento how can we know which particular product get updated?

Tags: csv, magento, import

In magento I am importing bulk products. Every month I gets CSV of whole data(all products). I want to upload only those product which attributes value actually got changed.

For example :

If I have 5 products in magento. I have csv with those 5 products. From those 5 products only 1 product's description get changed in new csv. So I want to import only that changed product.

If this is not possible then can we get all changed products after import ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should get an incremental csv, with only the data that's changed.

One thing that you could potentially do is, after loading the product and setting new data from the CSV, you can use `$product->dataHasChangedFor($field)` to determine if the new data is different than the original one for the particular field.

To see more about how this works, you can check the implementation in `Varien_Object`. Basically Magento stores original data that's loaded separately, so it allows comparing it with the newly set data.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so mean I need to check for all product's all attributes that is it changed or not by $product->dataHasChangedFor($field) ?